# Correct way to upload a file in serenity-screenplay

Tags: java, serenity-bdd

For now, using the latest serenity version (2.0.2) through maven I was able to simply perform an upload action like this:

```
import net.serenitybdd.core.annotations.findby.By;
import net.serenitybdd.screenplay.Actor;
import net.serenitybdd.screenplay.Task;
import net.serenitybdd.screenplay.actions.Upload;
import net.serenitybdd.screenplay.targets.Target;
import net.serenitybdd.screenplay.waits.WaitUntil;

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import static net.serenitybdd.screenplay.Tasks.instrumented;
import static net.serenitybdd.screenplay.matchers.WebElementStateMatchers.isVisible;

public class PerformTheUpload implements Task {

    public static Target UPLOAD_SOURCE_FILES_TARGET =
            Target.the("Upload source files").located(By.id("uploadSourceFiles"));
    public static final String TEST_FILE = "src/main/resources/files/test.txt";
    public static final Path TEST_FILE_PATH = Paths.get(TEST_FILE).toAbsolutePath();

    public static PerformTheUpload onTheField() {
        return instrumented(PerformTheUpload.class);
    }

    @Override public <T extends Actor> void performAs(T actor) {        
        actor.attemptsTo(WaitUntil.the(UPLOAD_SOURCE_FILES_TARGET, isVisible()));
        actor.attemptsTo(Upload.theFile(TEST_FILE_PATH).to(UPLOAD_SOURCE_FILES_TARGET));
    }
}
```

The problem with it is that it generates the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: POST /session/76ec390f-dbbe-48c2-be32-931969d81210/file did not match a known command
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'TAG-614', ip: '10.10.37.89', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 62.0.3, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.22.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 795608, moz:profile: C:\Users\alexandru.arcan\Ap..., moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, platformVersion: 10.0, rotatable: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
Session ID: 76ec390f-dbbe-48c2-be32-931969d81210
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'TAG-614', ip: '10.10.37.89', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution by implementing myUploadFile method:

```
...
import net.thucydides.core.pages.components.FileToUpload;

public class PerformTheUpload  implements Task {

    private WebDriver driver;

    public PerformTheUpload (WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public static PerformTheUpload onTheField(WebDriver driver) {
        return instrumented(PerformTheUpload.class, driver);
    }

@Override public <T extends Actor> void performAs(T actor) {        
        actor.attemptsTo(WaitUntil.the(UPLOAD_SOURCE_FILES_TARGET, isVisible()));
        myUploadFile(driver);
    }

    public void myUploadFile(WebDriver driver){
        WebElement webElement = getUploadWebElementById("uploadSourceFiles", driver);
        FileToUpload fileToUpload = new FileToUpload(driver, TEST_FILE);
        fileToUpload.fromLocalMachine().to(webElement);
    }

}

    //in the page class
    public static WebElement getUploadWebElementById(String id, WebDriver driver) {
        return driver.findElement(By.id(id));
    }
```